# Dragonfly Migration Worldwide

Tags: data-request, geospatial, biology

Looking for a dataset that holds sightings of dragonflies worldwide, preferably by species.

Should include date and Long/Lat and go back at least 5 years.

This could be from multiple sources where localised datasets are available so might need to combine into one answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iNaturalist has worldwide observations of biological organisms. You can do a bulk download [here](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/export). This data is not strictly "open", because login is required. However it is free to register.

Use this query to download observations of Suborder Anisoptera (Dragonflies): `quality_grade=any&identifications=any&taxon_id=47927`

There are currently 357100 observations of dragonflies, going back at least as far as 2000. The observations are identified, sometimes only to genus-level, often to species level. Identification is done by a combination of image recognition software and crowd-sourcing. Identification is more reliable (but still not 100% accurate) if you narrow the query to "research grade" observations. Most observations have photographs, so if you are an expert you can correct some of the identifications yourself.

Here are the instructions for bulk downloads from iNaturalist's FAQ:

> How can I download data from iNaturalist?
>
> Anyone with an account can export data from iNaturalist as a spreadsheet in csv format. You can start from the Explore page and click download in the lower right of the filters box. Or you can go directly to the export page (https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/export).
>
> If you plan to publish a paper using iNaturalist data, we recommend downloading iNaturalist data from the Global Biodiversity Information Facility because they will issue a citable DOI (see below for more details).
>   Source: https://www.inaturalist.org/pages/help#export